# Time series prediction with Lstm on patients data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, lstm

My data includes different time series length (depends on number of exams each patient did) as well the interval between exams is different.
How can I run lstm on this kind of data? (Where the sequence length is different)

How should I build the batch?
Should each batch hold a patient time series data?
Where do I put the target value?

Answer (score 0):

LSTM seeks inputs having the same shape. Hence, you may first consider defining a sequence length and then padding the sequences whose lengths are less than the defined sequence length.